# How to use shutil.rmtree.avoids_symlink_attacks?

Tags: python-3.x, symlink, shutil

I am currently working on a python script to be run on a linux machine and wonder how to use `shutil`'s `rmtree.avoids_symlink_attacks` function attribute.
The python documentation does not provide any example and I could not find any elsewhere.
So, can anybody post a minimal example on how to use it?

Comment: The purpose of ``rmtree.avoids_symlink_attacks`` is to *indicate* whether the *``rmtree`` implementation* is safe against symlinks attacks. You can't use it other than checking whether it is safe or not.

Comment: Ok, but how do I check it practically?

Comment: The same way you check any other boolean. ``if rmtree.avoids_symlink_attacks`` and so on. For example, ``if not rmtree.avoids_symlink_attacks: raise RuntimeError("rmtree is not safe on this Platform :(")``.

Comment: Ah, ok, now I got it (I was mislead by pycharm which highlights `avoids_symlink_attacks` erroneously with "reference not found"). Thank you.